# Please set the default workspace with MLClient

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

Getting error "Please set the default workspace with MLClient". How do I set the default workspace with MLClient? Trying to use data asset
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-register-data-assets?tabs=Python-SDK

```
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Data
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient

#Enter details of your AzureML workspace
subscription_id = "<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>"
resource_group = "<RESOURCE_GROUP>"
workspace = "<AZUREML_WORKSPACE_NAME>"
ml_client = MLClient(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace)
data_location='path'

my_data = Data(
    path=data_loacation,
    type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER,
    description="Data",
    name="Data_test")

ml_client.data.create_or_update(my_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Getting error "Please set the default workspace with MLClient". How do I set the default workspace with MLClient?

Make sure you have installed [`Python SDK azure-ai-ml v2(preview)`](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/tree/sdk-preview/sdk#azure-machine-learning-sdk-v2-preview-examples) using `pip install --pre azure-ai-ml`

You can try following code snippets taken from [workspace.ipynb](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/sdk-preview/sdk/resources/workspace/workspace.ipynb) to set the default workspace with MLClient:

**Import required libraries**:

```
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Workspace
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

ml_client = MLClient(DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id, resource_group)
```

**Creating a unique workspace name with current datetime to avoid conflicts**:

```
import datetime

basic_workspace_name = "mlw-basic-prod-" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime(
    "%Y%m%d%H%M"
)

ws_basic = Workspace(
    name=basic_workspace_name,
    location="eastus",
    display_name="Basic workspace-example",
    description="This example shows how to create a basic workspace",
    hbi_workspace=False,
    tags=dict(purpose="demo"),
)
ml_client.workspaces.begin_create(ws_basic)
```

**Get a list of workspaces in a resource group**:

```
for ws in my_ml_client.workspaces.list():
    print(ws.name, ":", ws.location, ":", ws.description)
```

**Load a specific workspace using parameters**:

```
ws = MLClient(DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id='<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>', resource_group_name='<RESOURCE_GROUP>', workspace_name='<AML_WORKSPACE_NAME>')
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to replace `<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>`,  `<RESOURCE_GROUP>` and `<AZUREML_WORKSPACE_NAME>` with actual values.
If you do that, the MLClient constructor will set the workspace accordingly.